# How to AND terms in zypper search?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

Suppose I want to search for the packet `luasocket` in OpenSUSE, but I don't know if it's called `lua-socket`, `lua_socket`, `liblua-socket`, `lua5.1-socket`, `socket-lua` or who knows what.

Therefore I make a search:

```
zypper se lua socket
```

The problem with this is it shows both packages containing `lua` keyword and also packets containing `socket` keyword, thus filling my screen with results I don't want.

`zypper search --help` tells the following:

```
   Command options:
     --match-all            Search for a match with all search strings (default).
     --match-any            Search for a match with any of the search strings.
```

But `--match-all` does not seem to work the way I expect. How can I AND terms when searching packets in OpenSUSE?

**Note**: If possible in a cleaner way than:

```
zypper se lua | grep socket
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be your cleanest option (as in easy to type).

You *can* do a regular expression in zypper:

From the help screen:

```
* and ? wildcards can also be used within search strings.
If a search string is enclosed in '/', it's interpreted as a regular expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
zypper se 'lua*socket'
```

Comment: That only works if you know in which order those words appear. What if I don't if the package I need is `mysql-python` or `python-mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex and/or more patterns search like this one:

```
sudo zypper search /lib.*Qt.*Chart/ /lib.*Qt.*Web/
```

as described in man page

```
search (se) [options] [querystring|capability]...
       Search for packages matching any of the given search strings. * and ? wildcard characters can be used within search strings. If the search string is enclosed in /  (e.g. /^k.*e$/) it’s interpreted as a regular expression. See the install command for details about how to specify a capability.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `zypper se mysql`

And you will get all info with 'mysql', then you can find out what you really want!

Comment: Are you suggesting to do filter *manually*, reading the entire screen output myself? That's worse than the `grep` workaround.